# Number of Applications vary in Oreo

Tags: applications, settings

I am using Motorola Moto X4 regular variant running android oreo 8.0.

- device not rooted
- not given permission for Unknown sources to install
- using stock launcher, stock os
- reset after oreo update

Before Oreo, device running in nougat with 66 apps installed (shown in Settings). After Oreo update I have done a factory reset, and skipped restoring one app with data, then settings showed 61 apps installed. But, if you count them it will be only 55 showed there. I don't have previous experiences with moto devices. Why such differences occur?

Comment: If you mean the differences between pre-Oreo and Oreo: Different versions ship with different apps. If you rather mean the 55 vs 61: some might be "hidden". That's usually the case for apps specific to a provider you are *not* with, or to a country you are *not* in.

Comment: That means they will be activated for specific country/service provider? @Izzy previously, few months ago,  I have asked a question about hidden app after installing apk. So  I got afraid that same may have happened here. But, that was in custom ROM, but this is stock ROM(which may never happen).

Comment: Exactly that, yes. They are restricted either to specific countries or providers (or both). For example, if you're in India, you have no need for an app specific to services by, say, a German provider. And some "legal stuff" might forbid you accessing some content served in the US. So those apps would be of no use for you.